# Laravel Vue VueRouter history mode

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm building an e-commerce project with laravel, vue and vue router

I want to use vue router with history mode but it cause me trouble.

Here is my code

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router: new VueRouter({
        mode: 'history',
        routes
    })
});
```

Here is my route in web.php which have locale middleware

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}', 'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'], 'middleware' => 'setlocale'], function () {
    Route::view('/{path?}', ('layouts.app'))->where('path', '.*');
});
```

Here is my route with vue router

```
export const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: require('./components/Page/HomePage').default,
    },
    {
        path: '/product',
        component: require('./components/Page/Product/ProductPage').default,
    },
];
```

I need my url to be

```
http://localhost/en
```

instead of (with the hashtag)

```
http://localhost/en#/
```

After using history mode, i successfully remove the hashtag. But, the router link of other will remove my locale in my url

```
http://localhost/product
```

I don't know what to do now with it.
Please help~ Thanks.

Update 19 Mar 2020
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set the [`base`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#base) value to tell Vue Router what the base URL of your application is. In your case you can set it dynamically using the locale value.

For example, in your Blade template you could have the following script to set the locale value on the JavaScript `window` object:

```
<script>
    window._locale = "{{ app()->getLocale() }}";
</script>
```

And then you can set the `base` value to the locale when creating your router:

```
router: new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: `/${window._locale}/`,
  routes
})
```

Comment: I tried but still the blank page showing with the history mode enabled..

Comment: What do you mean? You didn’t mention a blank page in your question.

Comment: @BlackLotus I created a demo for you on [Github](https://github.com/delenamalan/laravel-vuejs-locale-router).

Comment: i tried your demo ''http://localhost/clone/public/en/home'' But your demo also showing blank isn't it?

Comment: @BlackLotus It is because the "home" page is just at `/en/`. You didn't mention a `/en/home` route anywhere in your question.

Comment: I also tried  ''localhost/clone/public/en'' &  ''localhost/clone/public/en/'', it still give me blank page, i updated the image what i saw.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209929/discussion-between-blacklotus-and-delena-malan).

Comment: Super thanks. It's pretty important but sadly not mentioned in the Vue Router Guide, only in the API Reference: https://router.vuejs.org/api/#base

Answer (score 3):

Very simple way is too Accept the locale in Vue router too. So your route would be like this:

```
export const routes = [
    {
        path: '/:locale',
        children: [
        {
            path: '',
            component: require('./components/Page/HomePage').default,
        },
        {
            path: 'product',
            component: require('./components/Page/Product/ProductPage').default,
        },
        ]
    }
];
```

just be sure for children route dont put '/' in begining because its remove locale